# how many devices can be registered for iOS Enterprise programme

Tags: ios, iphone, developer-program

I am working in a big organization where I want to distribute application with 300 different devices.

I came to know that iOS Enterprise programme is available for such a big in house distribution ,

But I want to know how many device can be registered with such programe ?

With simple developer programe with ad-hock profile we are able to register  100 different devices that I know but with enterprise I do not have any idea.

If any one know then please let me know.

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's **unlimited**, tho I couldn't confirm it from any official source. There are [reports](http://discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=12457191) of people using it for way over 300 devices, tho, so you should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it's also 100 for the developer provisioning profile. But if the application is distributed using the distribution provisioning profile and not developer provisioning profile, it's unlimited.